# what does it mean"This status anxiety fuels the ambition needed to reach for success"?

Tags: sentence-meaning, learning

Is there anyone who explains it to me?

" This status anxiety fuels the ambition needed to reach for success."

Comment: *This / anxiety about my status / drives my ambition*. The posted sentence has too many words. The last five words are unnecessary.

Comment: ... I'm driven.

Comment: Reliable interpretation requires more context. Does this sentence occur in some kind of pep talk for young slackers, or in a work of socio-economic theory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be rephrased as:

- "However small, some anxiety is necessary to feed ambition, which in turn will make one fight for success."

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to paraphrase this.

Here is a first one.

- The worrying about status is a stimulation keeping alive all the time the  ambition necessary to be more successful.

Here is a second.

- The constant concern for status drives the ambition to have more success.